# Socket.io rooms not emitting

Tags: sockets, websocket, socket.io

In socket.io I made seperate rooms for clients when they need to sign up or log in to give them the info. But when I try to run this code it does not log 'hello' when telling the whole room to emit.

```
//client
function e() {
  io().emit('connection')
  io().emit('SignUp')
  io().on('check',function(t){
     console.log("Hello")
  });
}
e()

//server

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  const id=socket.id
  const room='r#'+id
  socket.join(room)
  socket.on('SignUp', function(User, Pass) {
    console.log(io.sockets.adapter.rooms.get(room).size)
    socket.emit('check');
  });
});
```

Its basically just sending a message to a single client really. I've tried socket.emit('check') and it just ignores it for no reason still. but when I use io.emit('check') it just works but still sends to all clients and can hack into random accounts. So thats all the details I can give on the problem if you have answers tell me.